# How to use SOS.DLL inside my project

Tags: .net, debugging, winapi

I want to extend my open source [Bug Finder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/602794/Bug-Finder-a-real-Win32-extensible-passive-debugge) project by adding the support for .NET managed processes faults.

Do anybody know how to interface my application with the WinDBG SOS.DLL extension shipped with the .NET framework?

Where I could find any usefull information about the above DLL?

Thank you much!

Antonio

Comment: By typing "sos.dll" in any search engine and [looking at the results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)? Or do you want to know [everything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/02/10263027.aspx)?

Comment: I've to link the SOS.DLL into my source code, instead looking at your link I found only the guide about how to use it by WinDBG.

Comment: It is a debugger extension.  Writing such an extension is [well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650659.aspx).  Using them without a debugger is not.

Comment: Here is something usefull : http://www.steveniemitz.com/Blog/category/IDebugClient.aspx ...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my site was linked on this so I'll try to give an answer.  You have three options here, an easy way, a sort-of-harder way, and a much harder way.

I'm assuming you already have an instance of IDebugClient in your app from looking at your codeproject site (also side note, codeproject? really?).  Given that, you can load the SOS extension with [IDebugControl::AddExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537892(v=vs.85).aspx), and then call commands on it with [IDebugControl::CallExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539023(v=vs.85).aspx).  This obviously isn't super great since all you get is strings out, however, this is directly answering your question, and is how to "use" SOS inside your app.

The next option is if you only care about .NET 4.5+, you can use my SDbgExt library (see my blog) to get the full backend of SOS exposed as a nice API.  I'd be happy to explain how use it, but doing so is beyond the scope of this site.

Finally You could also directly use the IXCLRDebugProcess interfaces, but doing so is fairly complicated.  Between .NET 4 and .NET 4.5, the interface completely changed, so if you want to support older .NET version you'd need to write two implementations.